# *ngFor specific condition Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have this code with `*ngFor`

```
settings = dropDownLists: [
   {name: 'Fac'},
   {name: 'Type'},
   {name: 'Course'},
   {name: 'Group'}
]

<div class="alingFloat" *ngFor="let dropDownList of settings.dropDownLists">
    <div class="scheduleText"> {{dropDownList.name}} </div>
</div>
```

HOW to print result like that?

```
<div class="alingFloat">
    <div class="scheduleText"> Fac </div>
    <div class="scheduleText"> Type </div>
</div>
<div class="alingFloat">
    <div class="scheduleText"> Curse </div>
    <div class="scheduleText"> Group </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show all template? Because i think you have two loops

Comment: Now i am lost you are asking HOW to print result like that or WHY result looks like that?

Comment: HOW to print result like that.

Comment: Can you change object settings ?

Comment: other question would be what if you have 6 items in your array will it be 3 blocks by two?

Comment: No I cannot change array. Look for my solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let dropDownList of settings.dropDownLists; let i = index;
                                                                  let even = even;">
    <div class="alingFloat" *ngIf="even">
        <div class="scheduleText"> {{settings.dropDownLists[i].name}} </div>
        <div class="scheduleText" *ngIf="settings.dropDownLists[i+1]?.name"> 
            {{settings.dropDownLists[i+1].name}} 
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Solution 2 and where I was staying

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let dropDownList of settings.dropDownLists; let i = index; 
                                                                  let even = even;
                                                                  let last = last;">
    <div class="alingFloat" *ngIf="even">
        <div class="scheduleText" *ngFor="let dropDownList2 of settings.dropDownLists | 
                                                slice:0: last ? 1 : 2; let k = index;">
            {{settings.dropDownLists[i+k].name}} 
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Instead of `<template ngFor...` you can use `<ng-container *ngFor` with the same `*ngFor` syntax like when used on normal (not template) elements.

Comment: Thank you @GünterZöchbauer. I changed my answer.

Comment: `<template>` isn't wrong, `<ng-container>` is just more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Simply refine your array/*ngFor on the basis of index no. and put the condition you want like this

```
settings = dropDownLists: [
   {name: 'Fac'},
   {name: 'Type'},
   {name: 'Course'},
   {name: 'Group'}
]



<div class="alingFloat" *ngFor="let dropDownList of settings.dropDownLists; let i=index">
    <div class="scheduleText" *ngIf='i == 0'> Fac </div>
    <div class="scheduleText" *ngIf='i == 1'> Type </div>
</div>
<div class="alingFloat" *ngFor="let dropDownList of settings.dropDownLists; let i=index">
    <div class="scheduleText" *ngIf='i == 2'> Curse </div>
    <div class="scheduleText" *ngIf='i == 3'> Group </div>
</div>
```

But this method is not generally preferred if you have undefined no of entry's in the array

Comment: Are you kidding?:)

Comment: oh. This method is a little dirty. Thanks for you time but need more clear

Comment: no m serious @VolodymyrBilyachat, btw whats wrong here ?

Comment: yeah @Lestoroer i already mention this method is not generally preferred. but this should work

Comment: First of all in each ngFor i starts from the beginning, secondly what if element if first element Fac will become value of Fox.

Comment: yes i know thats why i put condition like `i==1/2/3/4` and also this method is works only in case when we know the order or array elements.

Comment: But then what is difference when you just put html? what benefit from you code then? if you need to know order, amount of elements, and element names?

Comment: its depend on the condition how you will see , how you will render to the view.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whole case but if you want print div with two elements I would do smth like this

```
var initArray = [{ name: 'Fac' },
    { name: 'Type' },
    { name: 'Course' },
    { name: 'Group' }
    ];
    var settings =  initArray.reduce(function (prev, item) {
      var index = initArray.indexOf(item) % 2;
      if (!prev[index]) prev[index] = [];
      prev[index].push(item);
      return prev;
    }, []);
```

Then in template

```
<div class="alingFloat" *ngFor="let dropDownList of settings;">
    <div class="scheduleText" *ngFor="let element of dropDownList;"> {{element.name}} 1</div>
</div>
```

Result

```
<div _ngcontent-axv-3="" class="alingFloat">
    <!--template bindings={}--><div _ngcontent-axv-3="" class="scheduleText"> Fac</div><div _ngcontent-axv-3="" class="scheduleText"> Course</div>
  </div>
  <div _ngcontent-axv-3="" class="alingFloat">
    <!--template bindings={}--><div _ngcontent-axv-3="" class="scheduleText"> Type</div><div _ngcontent-axv-3="" class="scheduleText"> Group</div>
  </div>
```